# How to click on two or more elements in the same location

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a graphic chart that has some dots in it. These dots may locate in one place. I need to process click on two or more elements in the same spot. Is there any simple ways to do that in Vue 3?

I tried using refs and passing them to handleClick function so I can see which elements was clicked. But only higher element is responding to click.

Comment: what would help is "code"

Comment: the problem with overlapping elements (if I read your 2 vague pargraphs correctly) is that they overlap

Comment: The only way I can see to be able to do this is to add the click event handler to the containing element and then manually checking which of the children point elements have an overlapping bounding box with the clicked point. This is because AFAIK, the browser always has only a single element as the origin of an event, and it then bubbles up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try to use document.elementsFromPoint(x,y).
it will return every elements on that position.

Comment: You need to provide additional information on what needs to be done once you get the points between the x and y co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the click event to a function, you have x, y axis position of the click.

You can use this position to locate other dots and use javascript to click the element.

You can use getBoundingClientRect(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Alternate:
On a click, if a dot is hit.
Save the position of the click, and change the z-index of the object.
Perform another click on the same position with the x, y axis from click event, now hitting the new element on top.

Continue doing this, until the click event no longer is hitting dots.

For more context, reveal some code ;-)